# Derivative of a function composition

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I want to calculate if a function has a maximum or a minimum at $x= 1/2$.
$$G(x)= \int_{{0}}^{{x^2-x}} f(t) dt $$
Applying the fundamental calculus theorem i got the first derivative:

$$f(x^2-x)  *(2x-1) $$

I also know (from the excercise) that:

$$f(-\frac{1}{4}) = 1$$

I did this:

$$ ((2x-1) f'(x^2-x) (2x-1))+(f(x^2-x)2)$$

Then replacing with \frac{1}{2}, the function provides $2$, so in $x=\frac{1}{2}$ there is a minimum, it's ok?

Comment: Have you tried applying product rule to find G'' ?

Comment: I've edited my post

Comment: @Marco yes it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the second derivative. It may not even exist.

Let us assume that $f$ is continuous in a neighbourhood of $-1/4$. Then when $t$ is a little smaller or a little larger than $-1/4$, $f(t)$ is positive. That is because $f(-1/4)=1$.

So $G'(x)$ is negative when $x$ is close to $1/2$ but to the left of $1/2$, and $G'(x)$ is positive when $x$ is close to $1/2$ but larger than $1/2$.

So $G$ is decreasing immediately to the left of $1/2$, and then increasing. It follows that we have a local minimum at $x=1/2$.